# Is there a way to automatically release any unreleased dependencies of a project when calling mvn release:perform?

Tags: maven, dependencies, release

When releasing an artifact, which has unreleased dependencies (e.g SNAPSHOT), is there a way to tell maven to automatically release any unreleased project dependency?

Comment: simple answer to this is: No. A little bit more details: How should that work cause other deps could be located in any location on the internet etc. which means having different authentications etc.

Comment: If your artifact and the dependencies are all built in the same Jenkins, you can probably construct something like this, but I am no expert in Jenkins.